# mysql_fetch_row loop?

Tags: fetch

I set a session variable upon login, I want to find all rows in a table that have the username in the "Createdby" field and I want to list them on a page. I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE createdby = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] ."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo ($row[0]);
}
?>
```

It works great but it doesn't space them, it echoes out like: data1data2 and not separate like data1, data2. How can I customize the results without messing it up? I tried to add

```
echo ("<p>".$row[0]."</p>");
```

But received: 11, I'm kind of new to PHP.

Comment: echo $row[0]."</br>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply string concatenation. You're adding strings to other strings.

I'd suggest the following just to get started:

```
echo $row[0].", ";
```

I also suggest you read up on PHP more, as this is a basic concept in the language.

Comment: After reading the replies I feel like such an idiot, I'd blame the lack of sleep and it being the morning but this was actually really simple. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add spaces between each $row[0] like this:

echo $row[0] . ' ';

The dot followed by a space means that you're concatenating a space.